# Having two different servlets mapped on the same URL pattern

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I encountered a J2EE project written by others. When I come to the `web.xml`, there are two different servlets mapped on the same URL pattern. I wonder the purpose of this approach. How exactly does that work and what's the puspose?

Here is the relevant part of the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileDownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.htsoft.core.web.servlet.FileDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileDownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file-download</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileDownLoad</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.kaiwii.oa.action.system.FileDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileDownLoad</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file-downLoad</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: To paste the parts of the xml would be good.

Comment: i have already post the web.xml content yet.

Comment: Those aren't the same: the servlet spec states that pattern matching is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only one servlet will get called; there's no mechanism I'm aware of for handling a single request with two servlets (nor am I sure what that would even mean).

Servlet URL patterns may overlap, but having two with the exact same URL doesn't make sense. I don't recall if the servlet spec explicitly *disallows* it, however matching stops at the first matching. The matching method is defined in the spec.

[Servlet 2.4 spec PDF](https://jira.sakaiproject.org/secure/attachment/16135/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf) See p. 85+

Comment: The spec is pretty clear that the url-patterns must be tested in order of their occurrence, so the first longest match holds. SRV 2.5.

Comment: @EJP I thought that's what the mapping specifications portion did?

Comment: I amended my comment, but the parts that discuss filter mappings and security constraints are explicit about web.xml order; #11.1 that discusses <servlet-mapping> isn't.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, the spec *implies* it, but... you know how well *that* works out.

Comment: Exactly. It's a curious omission given how much work has taken place on it over more than ten years.

Comment: I haven't find in this spec that "url-patterns must be tested in order of their occurrence", also @WebServlet annotation doesn't have "priority" param.

Comment: What I've found in Servlet 3.0 spec: "The last filter in this chain is the last <url-pattern> matching filter in the deployment descriptor for this request URI. The last filter in this chain is the filter that invokes the first filter in the <servlet-name> matching chain, or invokes the target Web resource if there are none. " It's not very clear to me what they meant.

Comment: @MladenAdamovic  No surprise there, although I haven't verified this.